# Is it valid to have row number 2 without having row number 1 in CSS grid?

Tags: css, language-lawyer, css-grid

Is such a code valid?

```css
div {
  display: grid;
}

p {
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>asdf</p>
</div>
```

Seems to work, but this doesn't yet guarantee validity.

Reason: I'm populating the grid programmatically and not always all elements will be present. Only populating the second row seems an easier solution than special casing like "this kind of elements go to row 2 unless there was nothing in row 1 in which case they go to row 1".

Comment: Yes it's fine if you don't define any gap between rows or you define a row height. Add gap and you will see the difference. Note that the row one exist but is empty

Answer (score 0):

In CSS grid, you are allowed to create rows and columns (a/k/a, "tracks") on the fly. There's no need to define explicit tracks.

So your code is perfectly valid. You've used "line-based placement" to create an implicit row. Read more about this method here:

- [§ 7.5. The Implicit Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids)
- [§ 8.3. Line-based Placement: the `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end`, and `grid-column-end` properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement)